# Why does a styling attribute change inside a javascript url in an anchor modifies the document body content?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Insert the following link into an html document

```html
<a href="javascript:document.body.style.overflow='hidden'">hide scrollbar</a>
```

The result is an empty page (with the same url as before) with "hidden" as a value. The same code in "onclick" works as expected.

[image: A screenshot of firefox with an HTML document empty except for the word "hidden"]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet

Comment: Because it executes the javascript that hides the content.....

Comment: @epascarello the question is where does the document <html><body>hidden</body></html>  comes from.

Comment: because the url was not cancelled. The bookmarklet link above talks about it. It uses void to avoid the navigation. IN the end, please don't use links like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when a browser is to [evaluate a *javascript:* url](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#evaluate-a-javascript:-url)<sup>1</sup>, it will set the result of the script execution as the body of the response, if this result is a string:

> 7. Let evaluationStatus be the result of running the classic script script.
> 8. Let result be null.
> 9. If evaluationStatus is a normal completion, and evaluationStatus.[[Value]] is a String, then set result to evaluationStatus.[[Value]].
> 10. Otherwise, return null.
> 11. Let response be a new response with
>
> - URL:   targetNavigable's active document's URL
> - header list:   « (`Content-Type`, `text/html;charset=utf-8`) »
> - body: the UTF-8 encoding of result, as a body

Here the evaluation result is the string `"hidden"`:

```js
const evalResult = eval("document.body.style.overflow='hidden'");
console.log(evalResult);
```

Hence the Response that gets created contains this string as sole body, and that's what the browser will use to build the new Document when navigating.

<sup>1. Itself called from [navigate to a *javascript:* url](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#navigate-to-a-javascript:-url).</sup>